# Unable to get back a list of data from database after native query

Tags: spring

I am using Spring Framework and I have 2 Entitys, `User` and `Event` I am trying to add `entrants` to an event, I have made an `entrant` table

```
CREATE TABLE entrants (
   member_id BIGINT,
   event_id BIGINT,
   score INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (member_id, event_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES member
      (userid),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES event
    (eventid));
```

and I have made a query in my eventRepository to join the tables on the member_id and return only rows where the event_id matches a specific event.

```
//Get event entrants name, handicap and score
    @Query(value = "SELECT member.firstname, member.surname, member.handicap, entrants.score FROM member INNER JOIN entrants ON member.userid=entrants.member_id WHERE entrants.event_id=:eventid", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Entrant> getEntrantDetails(long eventid);
```

My controller,

```
//Get event entrants
    @GetMapping("event/getEntrants/{id:[0-9]+}")
    @CrossOrigin
    List<Entrant> getEntrants(@PathVariable long id){
        return eventService.getEntrantDetails(id);
    }
```

Event service

```
//Get Entrants
    public List<Entrant> getEntrantDetails(long id){
        return eventRepository.getEntrantDetails(id);
    }
```

In Spring I have my `user` and `event` Entity and I have also made an `Entrant` class as follows

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Entrant {

    private String firstname;

    private String surname;

    private double handicap;

    private int score;
}
```

When I try an make a `GET` request from postman to Spring I get the following error,
`"No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.syftgolf.syftgolf.event.Entrant]",`

Comment: Did you try the same query in JPQL?

Comment: I have never used JPQL before. I am quite new to using Spring JPA. This is one of the first I have had to write with the @Query Also, can I use JPQL if my `entrant` class is not an entity?

Comment: Euh... I missed the fact that `Entrant` is not an entity. You can't use JPQL in that case. But you can use a `Tuple` as a return type then parse it manually to extract the result.

Comment: So the data returned from the database is the user.firstname, surname and handicap and then the entrant.score. Are these returned as a Tuple? I then need to parse this tuple?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need make a Entrant's constructor with all attributs, for that the mapping works

Comment: Doesn't lombok @AllArgsConstructor  already create this?